# Is it possible to customise the look of grappelli?

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I'm building a site using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Grappelli](http://grappelliproject.com/). One of the requirements is to have a consistent theme across the entire site, both front end and admin interfaces.

At the least, the two things I would like to do are replace sections of the top bar to include the sites name (and logo) and customise the CSS for required fields to make them more obvious.

For example here: I'd like to replace "Grappelli" with "MySitename"

[image]

And below you can see the faint bolding indicates a required field, and I'd like to add some styling to make this stand out more:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't scrap grappelli as I'm using some of its advanced functionality like foreign key autocompletes and sortables, so that's not an option.

Sadly the [documentation doesn't really go into this detail regarding customisation](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html) and I'd rather not have to fork and override sections of Grappelli just for some small visual changes.

Is there any way to easily achieve this?

Comment: You don't need Grappelli documentation to override templates, Grappelli uses exactly the same techniques to override templates as Django does, you can find more information relating to template overriding / customization in Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/ 
Just copy the Grappelli templates in your projects template folder and override them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

to update the name just add GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = "MySitename" in your settings file

https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html